# Typescript property names dependant on outer type property values

Tags: typescript

I have the following interfaces (types would be fine too)

```
export type simpleValue = string | number | boolean | Date | null;

export interface Options {
  inline?: OptionsItem[] | unknown[];
  promptField?: string;
  selectedValues?: unknown[];
  valueField?: string;
}

export interface OptionsItem {
  prompt: string;
  value: simpleValue;
}
```

What I'm looking for is a way to pass the values of `promptField` and `valueField` to `OptionsItem` so they are used instead of `prompt` and `value` as property names.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the definition in the question. I've added it.

Comment: You will need generics and probably a helper function for inference, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w2vlVw). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @jcalz I found out that "casting" does not seem to work, I would expect it to. Maybe you could have a look? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKBLAtmANsANQENcBXVAXjgGcYoMA7AczgB84HSsAjYKNuNwgR8RBgIAiRGKnadcuANwAoZaEiwEyVAHkwMDBAbUAkjKwSYEADwAVYmVSgZDACbV02PIRLkANHAAClAQODAAYhjAuK5wzsBuHrT0zAEO5JHRsfGJNHSMTAB8cFQA3nDKcHAA2oFwjEEhYZkxALoAXHkpTIoVAL7KAGRw5ZU1BPXi6cAtrh1w9r7Avcp9KsoAxka0cBAAjJ16BttmwBZW1pw8fAEARGBN+rd3AG5Lt8VlYw+h+p33jxgzzGb0cnT2q3WW2M8AgACZDvpDMZTucbJgcPhpgFkgUcflmJ9dntFEA

Comment: I don't see any "casting" in that example, but I see you trying to widen to `string` which doesn't work because now you're saying that all string keys have both `string` and `TValue` properties, and `number` does work.  Is this a followup question?  If so it belongs in its own post.  Or does this post need to be [edit]ed to account for this before I write up my answer?

Comment: It is a follow up question, you answered this question just fine :)
I've posted the follow up here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77153661/typescript-defining-the-type-of-an-array-of-generic-intersection-types-where-the

Comment: Okay, I'll write up an answer here soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *specific* type in TypeScript which works this way.  Instead, you'd need to make your type [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in type parameters corresponding to the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `promptField` and `valueField` properties.  Something like this:

```
type OptionsItem<KP extends string, KV extends string> =
  { [P in KP]: string } & { [P in KV]: SimpleValue }

interface Options<KP extends string, KV extends string> {
  inline?: OptionsItem<KP & {}, KV & {}>[] 
  promptField?: KP;
  selectedValues?: unknown[];
  valueField?: KV;
}
```

The type `OptionsItem<KP, KV>` is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of two [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) equivalent to `Record<KP, string>` and `Record<KV, SimpleValue>` (using [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)).  An `OptionsItem<KP, KV>` has a `string` property at keys of type `KP` and a `SimpleValue` property at keys of type `KV`.

The `Options<KP, KV>` uses `KP` and `KV` in the appropriate places as well as passing them along to the `inline` property.  Note that I removed `| unknown[]` from that type because it completely obliterates things.  All values are of type `unknown` so an array will always match `XXX[] | unknown[]` for all `XXX`.  Assuming we want to catch errors, I've removed this.  Also note that I have actually used `OptionsItem<KP & {}, KV & {}>` instead of just `OptionsItem<KP, KV>`.  This is a trick mentioned in [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) to block inference.  Below we'll see that we really don't want to *infer* `KP` and `KV` from the `inline` property, we just want to *check* the `inline` property against `KP` and `KV` inferred from the `promptField` and `valueField` properties.

---

Anyway those types are what you want but presumably you wouldn't want to actually have to write out the type arguments like

```
const o1: Options<"p", "v"> = {
  promptField: "p",
  valueField: "v",
  inline: [{ p: "z", v: 123 }]
};
```

That would essentially require you write `"p"` and `"v"` more times than seems necessary.  When we have generic types like this, I tend to introduce a generic helper identity function to infer the type arguments.  Like this:

```
const asOptions =
  <KP extends string = "prompt", KV extends string = "value">(
    o: Options<KP, KV>) => o;
```

So now, instead of `const o1: Options = { ⋯ }`, we write `const o1 = asOptions({ ⋯ })` and the compiler infers `"p"` and `"v"` for us:

```
const o1 = asOptions({
  promptField: "p",
  valueField: "v",
  inline: [{ p: "z", v: 123 }]
});
// const o1: Options<"p", "v">
```

Note that in the call signature for `asOptions`, I have specified that `KP` and `KV` should [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `"prompt"` and `"value"`.  That means, if you pass in an object from which `KP` and/or `KV` cannot be inferred, the compiler should fall back to the default.  This gives you the following behavior:

```
const o2 = asOptions({
  inline: [{ prompt: "z", value: 123 }]
});
// const o2: Options<"prompt", "value">
```

So `o2` is inferred to be of type `Options<"prompt", "value">` and thus `inline` is checked against the default `{prompt: string, value: SimpleValue}`.  Here is where that `& {}` trick above is needed, by the way.  If you left off `& {}`, then the compiler would try to infer `KP` and `KV` from `inline`, and it wouldn't go well.

One more test:

```
const o3 = asOptions({
  promptField: "p",
  valueField: "v",
  inline: [{ prompt: "z", v: 123 }] // error
})
// const o3: Options<"p", "v">
```

Looks good, this error is what we want.  I've specified that `promptField` is `"p`" but then went ahead and used `prompt` instead of `p`, and the compiler duly complains about it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKBLAtmANsANQENcBXVAXjgGcYoMA7AczgB84HSsAjYKNuNwgR8RBgIAiRGKnadcuANwAoZYxlQAZkQDGqAPJgYGCA2oAeANIAFOKBkMAJtRp1GTADRxLBOyAfOrvTMAHxwAN7KcHCMuIzAAPwAXHCGxqbUAJIyWFa2AGQRAL5ePnCF4UUhANoAunAA9A3spAwA1gwQAO4MdYqNDXDmALTDCAAWGC4Q3HEa0sAuMJPM1FFwYFAQODAAYhjAuI7J3tYq0dSHwDoyjsRkiyetHd29tedwAG4k5PuHxykfCoiqokChUkYTGZssBcjY-AEXLRgp5vL57MAnEi3KE4BR1uE4NVbIxTrUUsj3HAiuUIkSSeIfOT0Ng8IQfqgQaodBl4ERqGkoS58dE8gjMYFKcw8XAAESbbZGWWldH+CXYlEy2XfB6ykIACnW0QgKUFGTyKpCAEo8WEICplDyzPAIABGGX8s1mfWRaIKnZ-I4peXK9Y634HINyz6h6KxeIpaqEsDBgBeyq+KVdACYAMzU2rKIpWlRNOBO2hwN2myHmkNebV67m8qvZj0C2ve30xBhxBjARPJrY7NMZ8MDuA5-NFQvF0uDCsu7M19Jmczy4dKhvjpuOlsQfNUT2d6g+9b+oyBxzBsCxr4cq-BmMedbx-uDjabmCjryfLN5gsBjsKAtigIsrWUMtFyrXMVyFddb23PUgA)