# TypeScript defining the type of an array of generic intersection types where the generic parameters are property names

Tags: typescript

I have a generic type `Options` where the generic parameters define the name of the two properties.
Now I need to put these into an array and define the type of that array in the type that holds the array.
However my code generates a union type out of the array effectively widen the type parameter to string which leads to the compiler no longer knowing which property is which.

```
export type SimpleValue = string | number | boolean | Date | null;

export type OptionsItem<TValue extends SimpleValue, PromptField extends string, ValueField extends string> = { 
  [P in PromptField]: string; 
}
& { 
  [V in ValueField]: TValue; 
};

export interface Template<TOptions extends OptionsItem<SimpleValue, string, string>[]> {
  options: TOptions;
}

const o1: OptionsItem<number, "prompt", "value"> = {
  prompt: "prompt",
  value: 1
};
const o2: OptionsItem<number, "x", "value"> = {
  x: "prompt",
  value: 2
};

let t: Template<[OptionsItem<number, "prompt", "value">, OptionsItem<number, "x", "value">]>; // The error is here
t = {options: [o1, o2]};
```

The error is

```
Type '[OptionsItem<number, "prompt", "value">, OptionsItem<number, "x", "value">]' does not satisfy the constraint 'OptionsItem<SimpleValue, string, string>[]'.
  Type 'OptionsItem<number, "prompt", "value"> | OptionsItem<number, "x", "value">' is not assignable to type 'OptionsItem<SimpleValue, string, string>'.
    Type 'OptionsItem<number, "prompt", "value">' is not assignable to type 'OptionsItem<SimpleValue, string, string>'.
      Type 'OptionsItem<number, "prompt", "value">' is not assignable to type '{ [x: string]: string; }'.
        Property 'value' is incompatible with index signature.
          Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Here is a link to the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKBLAtmANsANQENcBXVAXjgGcYoMA7AczgB84HSsAjYKNuNwgR8RBgIAiRGKnadcuANwAoZaEiwEyVAHkwMDBAbUAkjKwAeACrEyqUDIYATaumx5CJcgBo4ABSgIHBgAMQxgXCc4B2BnV1p6Zl9bcjCIqJi4mjpGJgA%20OCoAbzhlODgAbT84Rn9A4LTIgF0ALmzEpkVSgF9lADI4ErLKghrxFOBGp1a4Gy9gLuVulTVwaHhGGSgAMyIAY1QrYBxcaWBrPQMjV0yXOEvDYzNji0wTzztfBNyvnOY8ipNApFYYQfSPahtKwPa4qXrKPbXeAQACMbRhT3MFk4PD4vgARGB6vp8QSAG7zfEFYrDIlBfRtQnEmCk4YUuxtFFLFSI4zIgBM6PB12elhxvCgBJApLg%20PZ5CphUGwxAjLpwVZ5XlwDa-O5qnw8BgUOOeDOFgqGNMWPFeNl6pJ5MpeV8VtF2K4EqlMrlzqBXQA9AHZgALexQQL8DCuMNQYDKeDFMFXYxtCqo3wQflNZbKIA) showing the above code and error

Comment: It seems undefinable with current typescript features. The second line of error is the key. I see no way to describe type of array while keeping generic parameters of every element of substituting tuple type.

Comment: I mean, you can use `OptionsItem<SimpleValue, never, string>` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvyeAm) which is a proper supertype but it might not be as constrained as you'd like.  Does that meet your needs or am I missing something about it?

Comment: Unfortunately `never` does not work. I need the information that both properties are present and their keys are strings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the current types would allow for `PromptField` and `ValueField` to be the same.

Thanks to @jcalz mentioning that

```
export type OptionsItem<TValue extends SimpleValue, PromptField extends string, ValueField extends string> = { 
  [P in PromptField]: string; 
}
& { 
  [V in ValueField]: TValue; 
};
```

is actually equivalent to

```
export type OptionsItem<TValue extends SimpleValue, PromptField extends string, ValueField extends string> = 
Record<PromptField, string> & Record<ValueField, TValue>;
```

in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77154011/1378307),

it became apparent that I could use `Exclude<T,U>` to tell the compiler that they must never be the same.

```
export type OptionsItem<TValue extends SimpleValue, PromptField extends string, ValueField extends string> = 
Record<Exclude<PromptField, ValueField>, string> & Record<Exclude<ValueField, PromptField>, TValue>;
```

This makes the following code valid

```
let t: Template<[OptionsItem<number, "prompt", "value">, OptionsItem<number, "x", "value">]>; // The error is here
t = {options: [o1, o2]};
const p1 = t.options[0].prompt;
const p2 = t.options[1].x;
```

Link to [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2&ssl=21&ssc=27&pln=18&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKBLAtmANsANQENcBXVAXjgGcYoMA7AczgB84HSsAjYKNuNwgR8RBgIAiRGKnadcuANwAoZaEiwEyVAHkwMDBAbUAkjKwAeACrEyqUDIYATaumx5CJcgBo4ABSgIHBgAMQxgXCc4B2BnV1p6Zl9bcjCIqJi4mjpGJgA%20OCoAJWAAY2gnCwBREFKyJ2ALAKD9NMjkr2A2pzzfBNyCgDI4EvKoSpq60gaLFK7w9v9A4O7euBtOvJU1cGh4RhkoADMiUtQrYBxcaUarPQMjV0yXOHvDYzNLi0wrzzs%20nLMODDADeAF8AYkWKCwXkANoAXQKIOUcDgEH072oAC51m9HiowapysZ4BAAIy4-EfcwWTg8Pi%20ABEYGW%20iZzIAbp0mQUqCi0ayWjBcSy2TAOai4Ny7LjycowSoSbR0QAmKmYx6fSz03hQZkgDlwJky8i8wpwAVwECioXBSVo03AXGqhXbfDwEXrS54G4WOHU0y03WM4129lcnlrQPaulcPUGo0mqNIxRwAD06fWAAt7FBAvwMK5c1BgMp4PyMQ9jLi4RTfBBVQjFcplfAwOSLTAAHRVrFwgAMCO74ZgSse7dVXd7muMcPJw5AKiAA)